# Can I install Catalina as a secondary OS?

Tags: macos, mac, catalina

I was going to update my Macbook Pro from Mojave to Cataline, only that the rating of Catalina is 2.7 out of 5 stars on App Store, and if 1 is the lowest, so 2.7 means `(2.7 - 1) * 100 / (5.0 - 1.0)` meaning it is `42.5` point out of `100`.

So can I use another Macbook Air that had two partitions and dual boot of Mavericks and Sierra or High Sierra and upgrade perhaps the Mavericks to Catalina?

I need the Catalina so that I can run XCode, as XCode won't start unless it is Catalina.

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't use the star ratings as a metric of much. Some people will upgrade, but not check for incompatible software, which then causes problems, and they blame the OS. Some of those reviews may have been referencing bugs in early versions of Catalina that have since been fixed. You may want to read the reviews (and discount any that say "I installed Catalina and now my computer doesn't work!", or "My 32-bit apps don't work anymore!")

Comment: true, in the past I have upgraded to a new MacOS and the whole computer was unusable and I had to restore from the backup, and more recently for iOS 13 I have also upgraded to a new iOS and the iPhone won't boot up and I had to factory restore the whole iPhone, and I dare not upgrade to iOS 14 so soon... so... we can't rely on the upgrade too soon, and we can't rely on the rating of the App Store, what can we rely on?

Comment: Like all benchmarks and reviews you can only rely on your own tests. Which is why in large companies any os change has to be tested and all things running on it must be tested and signed off. Only you know what you run n

Comment: In practice with experience you get to know which bloggers a nd publications you can trust. Random reviewers will never be there. Although if many report the same issue then that might be a real probkem

Comment: @nonopolarity If a factory reset (i.e. an 'empty' phone with iOS on it) works, then the problem was not the OS. Each computer and phone is different, because of the apps installed and the data contained; the tasks you perform and the settings you select. It's more complex than "bad OS / good OS".

Comment: @benwiggy no, one time my photo album had some issue, it seemed, and then the photo album rebuilt itself.  And then, the new iOS 13 seemed to final reboot and then somehow alter the format in some way.  It would go on and on, and then stop at the last 95% of the progress.  I waited 1 week, 2 weeks, 3 weeks, hoping a patch would come out, and 3 weeks later, it was still stopping at 95%, so there seemed there is no solution and it will be an indefinite wait, so I can't wait 2 months, 6 months, or whatever because I needed to use my phone. So I factory reset it

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can boot to any number of OS versions that support your hardware, on different disks or partitions.

Bear in mind that High Sierra and later use APFS disk filing system, which Sierra can't read. So you can't put a Sierra volume on an APFS partition/container.

Comment: is it possible to partition into 2 parts, one for HFS+ and one for APFS?  Or... just two partitions and each partition can be freely either HFS+ or APFS?

Comment: High Sierra can also be installed to a JHFS+ volumes. I pretty sure Sierra can read from and write to APFS volumes.

Comment: @David Anderson, An experimental version of **APFS**, with some limitations, is available in **macOS Sierra** through the command line utility `diskutil`, but not thru the **Disk Utility** _application_. Personally, I would not use **APFS** in **macOS Sierra** as it was just an experimental version and does not have all the features present in the current **APFS**.

Comment: @user3439894: I believe that an update to Sierra was made available after the initial release of High Sierra which allowed Sierra to read and write to APFS volumes. I am not suggesting that Sierra can or should be installed in a APFS container. Also, I would not recommend using Sierra to create, resize, verify, repair or otherwise modify an APFS container.